# How to determine the parameters to split batch sql insert queries

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

## What I'm trying to solve

I'm trying to insert thousands/millions of product records into a mysql database with a query of the following structure:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO `Product` (productId, salesCounter) VALUES ?";
conn.query(sql, [products], function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    conn.end();
});
```

## My problem

The **products array** I'm trying to insert is extremely large so I'm assuming that the **products** array I pass into the query would have to be reduced into smaller sized arrays and run multiple insert queries instead to not overwhelm the server. My question is how do I determine the optimal size of the array partitions that would be sent for every insert query?

Comment: You can get the max allowed query size from the variable `max_allowed_packet`, by using `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'`.

Comment: Hey @Christopher thanks for the tip! My current max allowed packet size is 1,​048,​576 bytes so would this be a good solution?: 
1. Fill in an array of products until the array is close to the **max_allowed_packet_size** 
2. Send a query to the db with the reduced products array
3. Clear the prodcucts array and repeat the process until I've processed all products

Comment: Yes. This would be it. -- But keep in mind that different encoding require more bytes to be transfered. -- You can also increase the value of the read only var [`max_allowed_packet` up to 1GB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) by editing the server config file.

Comment: I didn't even think of the encoding part! Thanks for taking time out of your day to help, I appreciate it a lot! I will be writing some js for this and include it in the question above :)

Comment: If you have a solution you can also post it as an answer and [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for this question.